# Error correction code handling deletions and insertions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, information-theory, coding-theory

I have data which is expressed in form of fixed-length sequence of decimal digits, typically 10 digits in length.

I'm looking for error correction code that would allow me to append one or more characters to the end of my digit sequence and prevent data from being corrupted following ways:

1. Individual char replacement (`...12345 => ...92345`)
2. Swapping of two neighbor characters (`...12345 => ...12435`)
3. Deletion of character (`...12345 => ....1245`)
4. Insertion of character (`...12345 => ..123X45`)

I can extend an alphabet of digits to include hexadecimal digits too in sake of reliability, so redundant code can use `A-F` letters too. When represented number is smaller than it's required, I can pad it either way with some pad symbol, which could be either plain zero or in range `A-F` if necessary.

I would greatly appreciate if this code will not have an overhead larger than two lengths of message itself.

I've already looked at Reed-Solomon code implementations, but as I lack finite field math knowledge yet, I was able only to play with existing implementation over GF(2<sup>8</sup>) — I packed the number as 32-bit representation, applied various kinds of distortions and could only achieve stability with error code itself being twice as long as message itself (e.g. 64 bits), so now I'm searching for something shorter.

Does the code like above exist? If no, could you please point out to restrictions that have to be relaxed in order for it to exist?

Comment: "[...]prevent data from being corrupted[...]" Are you looking for error correction, or just error detection?

Comment: Your data packets are so short that I would try an RS-code over $GF(2^4)$. I need to think about the necessary amount of redundancy. Can you always tell from the received message that an insertion/deletion has taken place? IOW are your data packets of a constant length?

Comment: A probably related topic: [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Another useful buzzword may be the error detection code used in Norwegian social security numbers. People often refer to that as a model for protection agains this type of errors. I have sat at a dinner table with the dude who designed that code on a number of occasions, but I have never familiarized myself with the details of the construction. You may be able to find something by googling that :-)

Comment: @Snowball, I'm looking for error correction, as error detection can be achieved by some kind of CRC only — this will not give me way to restore original message.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, no, unfortunately, I currently cannot determine insertion or deletion. Data packets formally are variable in size, but have upper length bound (10 chars) and can be zero-padded out to constant width to aid ECC.

Comment: Is a "char" the same as a "hexdigit" for you (IOW 4bits)? Can you stomach to have all the data packets zeropadded to for example 10 chars, encoded to say 14 or 16 chars, so that it will be obvious from the received message width that a deletion or insertion has taken place, and you want the ECC to tell what was deleted/inserted and where? I mean, if the probability of data packet consisting of only 2 or 3 chars is relatively high, then you may not want to pay the price of zeropadding that to ten chars :-).

Comment: Or did I get it right that you would rather have the ECC to add, say, 4 chars worth of redundancy to a packet of an unknown length ranging from 1 to 10 chars with the hope that the ECC can then detect and correct an insertion/deletion as well as the more common error events?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, latter one :) Yes, "char", "hexdigit" and "4-bit symbol" in my case are the same. Probability of data packet having length less than five is very low, and if the only obstacle is minimal length, it can be easily circumvented by adding some number before encoding, and having that number subtracted after decoding, so this is not a problem really. Your latter scenario is actually what I want to achieve — having uniform overhead on top of encoded message, be able to reveal original message from the one corrupted by mentioned methods.

Comment: I'm having second thoughts about the use of an RS-code. Need a scheme that can detect the absence of a trailing zero symbol :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, you get '12356FA', where 'FA' are digits added by ECC and '12356' is corrupted data. If my hypotetical ECC operates fixed-length strings, I left-pad packet to be 10+2 chars wide, and it's now '0000012356FA', feed it to ECC decoder and suppose to get '12345' in response, either padded or not. No need to track trailing zero, as padding will only add insignificant zeros. Even if I'm forced to do right-padding, I can just reverse the string.

Comment: I think a repetition code with a parity digit should work, e.g., $3461 \mapsto 33446611\underline{4}$, where $\underline{4} = 3+4+6+1 \text{ mod } 10$. It should be able to handle 1 instance of each of the corruptions you mentioned (independently). I didn't work out the decoding details, but you might want to give it a closer look.

Comment: @Snowball, first look on your approach tells me I would have decoding problems if corruption will hit error code suffix itself. But thanks, I have to look into this further...

Comment: @modchan: I don't think there's any issues involving the parity digit if the corruption hits it, as long as there's only one instance of the corruption. If there's an insert/delete in the last or second-to-last position, there will be no problem, since the first $2k$ message digit pairs will all match each other. If there's a swap involving the last two digits, you'll know because the final pair will have 2 different values *and* the parity bit won't match the sums over the first values in each pair (i.e., $w_0+w_2+\ldots+w_{2k}$, where $k$ is dimension).

Comment: Take a look at chapter 7 of "[Error-correction on non-standard communication channels](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/ear23/papers/)".

Answer (score 5):

The capacity of channels with deletions and insertions remains poorly understood. Still some lower and upper bounds are known, you can easily google for that.

As for codes that work under such circumstances you also have some literature to browse, I'd suggest that you take a look at the seminal work by MacKay and Davey: "[Reliable communication over channels with insertions, deletions, and substitutions](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/910582)" and from there you can explore the different works citing it.

Comment: The first work would probably be Levenstein's paper (cited in the next paper), which a very nice updated result is given in arXiv:1302.6562 [cs.IT] (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.6562.pdf) - Cullina, Kiyavash "An Improvement to Levenshtein's Upper Bound on the Cardinality of Deletion Correcting Codes".